# SPS 2010 Configuration of New Installation

Tags: installation, configuration-wizard

For the past couple of days I have been setting up a brand new SharePoint Server 2010 running on top of Server 2008.  This installation is intended to be used with Active Directory and will be used as an intranet for our organization.  Everything installed correctly and the SharePoint install itself went fine.

I'm at the point now where I am running the SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard.  The thing that is bothering me is that the configuration wizard runs without me needing to enter any information (Service Accounts, Database Server, Admin Site Port, etc).  Should I have done something different during the installation to be able to enter this information?  Or is it all just handled by the Central Administration Site when using AD?  I've read a couple of places that mentioned opening the Management Console and making a new SP Configuration Database, but this was always predicated by the fact that it was needed to use local accounts with the SharePoint deployment.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you have done a stand alone installation when you installed the bits. This changes everything. You should always do a Server Farm install, even if you are putting everything on a single machine. The only way to repair this is to uninstall SharePoint and install it using the Server Farm installation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the stand alone installation is not recommended as well. So, Always try to install Farm type and if you select farm with complete installation then you will be asked for the database, central admin port number, credentials in step 3 of 10. Let me know, if you need any further information.